# How to type Firebase getDoc when using vue-concurrency?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a TypeScript Vue composable using Firebase and [vue-concurrency](https://github.com/MartinMalinda/vue-concurrency).

The [docs say I have to explicitly type](https://vue-concurrency.netlify.app/typescript-support/#known-limitations) any intermediate values that were yielded.

And I am trying to do that for a Firebase `getDoc` call, but Eslint is giving me an error saying `Unsafe assignment of an 'any' value` which I would like to solve:

```
import { db } from 'src/firebase/config';
import {
  doc,
  getDoc,
  // DocumentData,
  DocumentSnapshot,
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useTask } from 'vue-concurrency';

const getDocumentTask = useTask(function* (
  signal,
  collectionName: string,
  documentId: string
) {
  const documentReference = doc(db, collectionName, documentId);
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
  const response: DocumentSnapshot = yield getDoc(documentReference); // <-- Eslint error here
  const document = {
    ...response.data(),
    id: response.id,
  };
  return document;
});

export default getDocumentTask;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, just found the answer (at least in my case).

Replace

```
'firebase/firestore'
```

with

```
'firebase/firestore/lite'
```